# discord.py how to set bot to specific channels

Tags: discord.py

I'm terribly sorry if this is a very dumb question, as I'm fairly new to Python. I wanted the bot to have a command to set to a specific channel. It sets it correctly, but it isn't set correctly in other commands. I've tried various solutions, and none of them seem to work.

````
client.remove_command("help")
current_channel = 100 #placeholder

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} is now running")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")


@client.command()
async def setChannel(ctx):
    current_channel = ctx.channel.id
    await ctx.send("channel set to here.")
    await ctx.send(current_channel)
    return current_channel

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id != current_channel:
        await ctx.send("not correct channel, channel is set to")
        await ctx.send(current_channel)
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send("```insert help message here```")
        return
````

[and the results turned out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A05Wq.png)

I've tried to use asyncio.gather() and various other possible solutions but those just gave me the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the value of a global variable in a function, you need to specify the variable as global:

```py
@client.command()
async def setChannel(ctx):
    global current_channel

    current_channel = ctx.channel.id
    await ctx.send("channel set to here.")
    await ctx.send(current_channel)
    return current_channel
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much